# Recovering accidentally deleted files, block device

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally deleted `/dev/loop` special block device. Is it possible to recover it?

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the device with `mknod`:

```
sudo mknod -m 660 /dev/loop b 7 0
```

assuming that you don't have `/dev/loop0` that already has taken that minor number (`0`)

Comment: the main problem is that ; I want to mount an iso image so I'm using that command (mount -t iso966 -o loop "iso image path" mount point) and it still doesn't recognize /dev/loop . U understand me ?

Comment: @AsmaSarhan That is essentially a different problem. After creating the loop device with `mknod` use `mount -t iso9660 -r -o loop "iso image path" /dev/loop`. You need to do it read-only (`-r`) and your type was wrong (missing a `0`) at the end. Post a new question if there are additional problems, including the exact command you use and error message.

Comment: Can you explain how\why you used those parameters for mknod?

Comment: @SailorCire Yes I can. (I specify the parameters on the commandline)